# Using multiple Nameservers to use different services

Tags: dns, domain-registrar, nameserver

Well, my question is pretty simple, but I don't know what to do exactly because I don't know my possibilities.

I bought a domain at name.com. This website also provides a DNS resolving service.

I have a Jekyll website (using Github Pages) configured with Cloudflare, so, I need to use their nameservers at name.com domain config:

[image]

To point to my domain: `www.mydomain.example` and `mydomain.example`

I have done this already, and everything is working.

But also, I'll need to use a hosting to upload some backend files (PHP) and to host some documentation for my products.

My hosting says that I'll need to use their nameservers:

[image]

But Cloudflare doesn't support Custom Nameservers for free... So, I have to use the name.com DNS configuration to achieve this...

But, wait a minute, name.com warns me about the following:

[image]

So, I can't use at the same time Cloudflare/name.com nameservers and the nameservers from my hosting, what could I do?

**EDIT:** I have seen that http://www.xname.org/ can do something with nameservers... But I'm not sure about the utility that it offers.

Comment: You don't need to change name servers because you just add the IP addresses of your servers within DNS cloudflare, all good hosts support this, if yours don't - find a GOOD host.

Comment: I just found a free one, right now I can't afford a paid one.

Comment: Right, then you won't be able to use many services such as Cloudflare. Free hosting is gimped purposely, they are not ideal hosts but with Github pages you use CNAMES which can be configured in CLOUDFLARE.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no way to attach multiple nameservers to a single top-level domain name.

However that being said, there is no reason that your hosting should *require* you to use their nameservers, unless you have some nonstandard hosting requirements that I am not aware of. Most hosting only requires you to log into whatever nameserver service you are using (in this case CloudFlare) and point `A` and/or `CNAME` records at the hosting.

Now I'm sure you are aware that for a single domain/subdomain you will not be able to use both GitHub Pages hosting and Byet hosting at the same time. But you can put them on different subdomains (e.g. GitHub Pages / Jekyll hosting at `example.com` and `www.example.com`, and Byet hosting at `docs.example.com`).

Comment: The problem here is that I'm using Github Pages as a hosting, Jekyll is the content generator... So I need to point two "hostings" using Cloudflare.

Comment: Like I said, you can use two hosts on separate subdomains (which I or anyone else could help you with), but you cannot trivially use two hosts on the same subdomain.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your requirements I'll suggest that you proceed with the following steps:

Solution 1

1. Export your DNS records on Cloudflare to keep a backup copy.
2. Go to name.com switch to the new nameservers.
3. Update your DNS on your new host with the records exported from Cloudflare.

Solution 2.

Or better still, just use Heroku to host your PHP files, use JawsDB on Heroku for your MySQL all these you can do without having to change your nameservers pointing to Cloudflare.

Comment: Two problems happen looking at your answer. I can't customize DNS on my hosting because it doesn't offer this features and using Heroku I don't have to do any CNAME or something like that by its part? Maybe I only need to point to the IP that Heroku gives. But I'm not sure...